# Django FastCGI shared hosting configuration

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, fastcgi

I'm trying to configure my webserver so I could run my Django application on it with FastCGI.

Here is my setup production server architecture:

```
www/
    project/
        [other project files and folders]
        .htaccess
        .project.fcgi
```

#### project.fcgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os

# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/my/python")

# Switch to the directory of your project. (Optional.)
# os.chdir("/home/user/myproject")

# Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "project.settings.production"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

#### .htaccess

```
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ project/project.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now when I refresh the page, I get a `500 Internal Server Error`.

Error Logs:

`Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Because I'm on a shared hosting, I have no access to modify the httpd.conf file in order to set the logs to a different level so there is not much information form me to understand what's the problem.

Any help would be highly appreciated.